# select data based on three values from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table in this format

```
userid  = int
amount  = int
company =string
status   =int 
submission_time = date/time
approval_time   =date/time
```

I want to sum amount of each userid, differentiated by userid , status , and submission_time{date} 30 days old

My idea for query.

```
 SELECT sum(amount) as total,* FROM Tablename
 WHERE status=0 and submission_time<=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
```

I am not able pick data based on userid , status , and submission_time{date 30 days old.}

Kindly help me in building this query.

Comment: Do you want to count `amount` field or sum it?

Comment: You haven't said what is currently happening, but my guess is that you get a MySQL error, because `count(*)` and `,*` don't belong together. `count(*)` is an aggregate function: it counts a number of rows. `,*` is trying to output the contents of each row. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i have edited.. i want to sum amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 30 days old records only, try following query.

```
SELECT userid, SUM(amount) as total FROM Tablename
WHERE status=0 AND submission_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
GROUP BY userid
```

I'm still not sure you want to use `COUNT()` for `amount` column, as per my thinking you should use `SUM()`

Comment: you are right. that was typo ., it was sum. i have edited question

Comment: Have you checked my above answer is giving the desired output or not?

Comment: i am testing it .. will update here